# Yii2 Querybuilder with searchmodel

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

My searchmodel

```
$query = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select(['monthsubmit',"DATE_FORMAT(monthsubmit, '%m-%Y') as c_date", 'modeler', 'count(sku) as count'])
    ->from('sku3d')
    ->groupBy(['monthsubmit', 'modeler'])
    ->orderBy(['monthsubmit'=>SORT_DESC, 'modeler'=>SORT_DESC]);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
```

My controller

```
    $searchModel = new Sku3dSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
```

My gridview

```
<?php echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel'=>$searchModel,
    'pjax'=>true,
    'panel' => [
        'type' => GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,
        'heading' => '<h3 class="panel-title"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i>Submitted SKU by Month</h3>',
    ],
    'columns' => [
        [
        'attribute'=>'monthsubmit', 
        'width'=>'310px',
        'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(Sku3d::find()->orderBy('monthsubmit')->asArray()->all(), 'monthsubmit', 'monthsubmit'), 
        'group'=>true,
    ],
        [
        'attribute'=>'modeler', 
        'width'=>'180px',
        'group'=>true,
        ],

        'count:text:Total Sku',
    ]
]); 
?>
```

At first I didn't use querybuilder in searchmodel but in controller and everything worked fine. But I need to filter it also so i moved my querybuilder into searchmodel.

When I did this, it had error "Getting unknown property:app\models\Sku3d::count".

How can I call the `'count(sku) as count'` to my gridview. And also it look like my `groupBy(['monthsubmit', 'modeler'])` not working also.

Please tell me where I'm wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: add `public $count;` variable in your `Sku3d` model inside class.

Comment: or something like this: ->select(['COUNT(sku) AS count']).

Answer (score 2):

In your searchmodel  add  a publica var

```
class Sku3dSearch extends Sku3d
{

    public $count;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()

    ......





    $query = (new \yii\db\Query())
        ->select(['monthsubmit',"DATE_FORMAT(monthsubmit, '%m-%Y') as c_date", 'modeler', 'count(sku) as count'])
        ->from('sku3d')
        ->groupBy(['monthsubmit', 'modeler'])
        ->orderBy(['monthsubmit'=>SORT_DESC, 'modeler'=>SORT_DESC]);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);


}
```

Comment: And add count to to validation rules as safe attribute

Comment: `Getting unknown property: app\models\Sku3d::count`, still get this error :(

Comment: try move the public $count in the model instead of the searchModel

Comment: Solved the error but the `count` field is Null (not set). Don't have any value

Comment: have you removed  the public $count  from searchModel??

Comment: @scaisEdge yes I have

Comment: Please help me with this, I really can't get this to work at all

Comment: try change the name of the var and the name of the alias ..  eg  $mycount 
 and as mycount instead of count  (both  the var name and the alias  name)

Comment: still get `(not set)` value :(